# Ruby 1.9.3 breaks rake test

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, ruby-1.9.3

I have an existing rails 3 project that works just fine on ruby 1.9.2-p290. However upgrading to ruby 1.9.3-p0 causes `rake test` to spit out the following error:

```
/Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:167:in `block in non_options': file not found: test/unit/**/*_test.rb (ArgumentError)
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `map!'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `non_options'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:207:in `non_options'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:52:in `process_args'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:891:in `_run'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
/Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:167:in `block in non_options': file not found: test/functional/**/*_test.rb (ArgumentError)
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `map!'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:146:in `non_options'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:207:in `non_options'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:52:in `process_args'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:891:in `_run'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:884:in `run'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:326:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
from /Users/zmanji/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit.rb:325:in `block in autorun'
```

It seems to be a consequence of this [rake issue](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/51). However when I create a simple rails project on ruby 1.9.3 so such error occurs. What can I do to get my rails project to run on ruby 1.9.3?

Comment: Which rails version are you using in your Gemfile? I have just tested a new app on rails 3.1.1 and ruby 1.9.3 p0 - the rake test works ok.

Comment: I have rails 3.1.1 in my Gemfile. It should also be noted that if I change rake to the 0.9.3.beta.1 it works. However it is not desired to use a beta version of rake with the project.

Comment: Is it desired to work with Ruby x.x.x-p0 ? It is usually worse than gem beta.

Comment: The speedup from working with ruby 1.9.3 vs 1.9.2 for a rails project is about 33% with my projects. If my tests run 33% faster it is worth it.

Comment: If so, consider beta rake also.

Comment: Yeah, if you're willing to use a 0 patch of a language, then a beta release of a stable gem shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: As I see you are running bundled test/unit. Ruby 1.9.x extracted the test unit to it's own gem. Try to use that, maybe it's already patched for your bug. http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Are you using bundle exec when calling rake? bundle exec rake test

Comment: Strongly disagree with p0/beta gem comparisons. Ruby release cycle is *far* more stringent than most gems.

Comment: I agree with @XavierShay here, 1.9.3-p0 is *not* a beta or other pre-release version. It is a full-on officially released version. Patch level is **not** the same as "beta", "RC", or "preview". There was a  preview & RC release of 1.9.3, but 1.9.3-p0 is a release version.

Answer (score 9):

Adding the test-unit gem worked for me.

Comment: Hmm. No change for me when I tried it. (Currently attempting to see if using the latest ruby, patchlevel, 1.9.3-p194, makes a difference)

Answer (score 6):

Try the following (independently):

1. Use `test.test_files = FileList['test/unit/**/test*.rb']`
2. Remove `shoulda` beta dependency.
3. Use `test/unit` gem.

Comment: Removing shoulda fixed that for me

Comment: Removing shoulda worked (as did adding test-unit), but as I was using RSpec and still needed shoulda, I replaced `gem 'shoulda'` with `gem 'shoulda-matchers'` which seems to work just fine. Thoughtbot's documentation does say that only shoulda-matchers are needed for RSpec, and shoulda-context is used "If you're not testing a Rails project or don't want to use the matchers".

Answer (score 4):

The `shoulda` gem is causing a general problem when using `rake` in test environment on ruby 1.9.3, this is repported in [this issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/223).

### Workaround

You can use this line

```
gem "shoulda", :require => false
```

in your Gemfile and then somewhere in your test code (e.g. `test/test_helper.rb` if you are using test-unit) you can put

```
require 'shoulda'
```

If you are using rspec you should not use the `shoulda` gem at all, you should use the `shoulda-matchers` and this will not cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

We changed our rake task (rake file) to look like this

```
require 'rake/testtask'
  ...
desc "Run all tests in folder tests/test*.rb"
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['tests/test*.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

based upon: http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TestTask.html